# Cannot read property 'map' of undefined

Tags: javascript

I have an error of Cannot read property of map, I'm trying to display a table of content on my page by getting the data from the database using restful API and store it into an array.
first time I open the site everything works fine and it displays the table with no problem but when I refresh it gives the error.

This is my function for getting the data and display it in a table using map:

```
const ListTodos = ()=>{
    const [todos,setToods]=useState([]);
   
        const getTodos = async ()=>
        {
            try{
                const res = await fetch("http://localhost:3080/get")
                
                console.log(res)
                   const jsondata = await res.json();
                   setToods(jsondata);
            }catch(err){
              
                console.error(err.message);
            }
        }


        useEffect(() => {
            getTodos();
          }, []);
          
          arr = todos[0];

 
      
      return (
          <Fragment>
      <table class="table mt-5 text-center">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>ID_Event</th>
            <th>Name_Event</th>
            <th>Date</th>
            <th>Address</th>
            <th>Duration</th>
            <th>Description</th>
            <th>Delete</th>
            <th></th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        
        {arr.map(arr => (
            <tr>
              <td>{arr.ID_Event}</td>
              <td>{arr.Name_Event}</td>
              <td>{arr.Date}</td>
              <td>{arr.Address}</td>
              <td>{arr.Duration}</td>
              <td>{arr.description}</td>
              <td>
              <button className="btn btn-danger" onClick={() => deleteevnet(arr.ID_Event)}>Delete</button>
              </td>
            </tr>
          ))}
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </Fragment>
                );
      }
```

Comment: `arr = todos[0];` what is this supposed to do?

Comment: well this is a temporary solution because when I get the data back from the database using the API it returns two arrays, one empty and one with the data, so the one with the data is todos[0]

Comment: You should not be reassigning the data to arr. You should use todo[0] && todos[0].map... and remove the arr = todos[0].  You also can have scoping issues by calling the variable arr and using arr as the variable in the map.

Comment: @SeanW will fix that but I used this as a temporary solution thanks a lot for the advice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By writing `arr = todos[0]` on top level you are creating a **global** variable which is `undefined` until the data is fetched (first element of empty array).

You should declare it ideally as `const` so it is **local** to the functional component, and handle the case when it's `undefined` with something like:

```
{arr && arr.map(arr => (
            <tr>
              <td>{arr.ID_Event}</td>
              <td>{arr.Name_Event}</td>
              <td>{arr.Date}</td>
              <td>{arr.Address}</td>
              <td>{arr.Duration}</td>
              <td>{arr.description}</td>
              <td>
              <button className="btn btn-danger" onClick={() => deleteevnet(arr.ID_Event)}>Delete</button>
              </td>
            </tr>
          ))}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add a conditional so it runs when your `arr` is not `undefined`:

```
{arr !== "undefined" && arr.map(arr => (
```

> React evaluates our return statement, when it hits the arr.map(...)
> line its actually running undefined.map(...) which is obviously an
> error in JavaScript.

Read more [here](https://www.debuggr.io/react-map-of-undefined/)

Answer (score 1):

Use the following programming construct to ensure the `arr` has value inside it:

```
{arr && arr.map(arr => (
  // ...
))}
```

The `useEffect` hook works asynchronously so on the first run the `arr` would be `undefined`:

```
arr = todos[0]; // [][0] === undefined
```